# How to implement custom logic for submitting Survey to still display users inputs after passing survey validation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, survey

I have problem. I am developing web APP. Front-end is made using React.js and MUI library.
In some part of project  I have page where user can create Consent. Consent have permissions to add. Permissions have their Responses. For example. Permission - "Do you agree what StackOverflow if awesome?" Responses would be- "Yes", "No" and "Something else"

In page filling-consents I need to implement logic what user can fill Consent, I mean here answer on Permissions. And this data save to DB.

Problem is what I can display Permissions and their Responses using SurveyJS, also validate and show errors. BUT, I need implement custom logic.
[Consent Filling Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJORx.png)

If user click on Commit button(Green one in image)

1. On buttons click, check if all Permissions were answered if not show Error message, for this I use SurveyJS survey.validate(false, true); method stop function execution
2. If user answered to all Permissions, survey.validate(), will return true, I show prompt to user. "Do You really want to save you answers", and have two buttons "Continue" and "Cancel"
   2.1) IN case user presses "Cancel" close up prompt
   2.2) In case user presses "Continue" when responses are send to Back-end and stored in DB. prompt closes and navigates user to previous page.

According docs for surveyJS object you need add to JSON what is responsible for Surveys(their questions and answers)
showNavigationButtons: false, // do not show in Survey navigation button and complete button, because custom logic will be implemented
showCompletedPage: false,// do not show complete page, because I want after user ocmpleted Survey show users responses

- to validate data you need to use survey.validate()
- to set what Survey is complete you need to use
- survey.doComplete(); // get results of survey, and makes what you can not see user answers
- const surveyQuestions = survey.getPlainData(); // using this function I get users responses

**And I entered several problems.**

- If user answered questions of survey and presses "Commit" button, then all user responses are cleared, but in surveyJS. data property you contain users answers.
  Question is how to display all the time users answers? Surveyjs hides it from user. In case user wants Submit COnsent but on prompt figure out what it does no want to.